# Why doesn't guard create unwrapped var?

Tags: ios, swift2, forced-unwrapping, guard-statement

Why do I need to unwrap the variable `unwrapped` in the final return statement?  Isn't guard supposed to handle this?

```
func test() -> String {
    let fmt = NSNumberFormatter()
    let myValue:Double? = 9.50
    guard let unwrapped = myValue else {
        return ""
    }
    return fmt.stringFromNumber(unwrapped)
}
```

> error: value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to
>   use '!' or '?'?
>       return fmt.stringFromNumber(unwrapped)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the variable `unwrapped`. It's `stringFromNumber`: it returns an optional string. But your function returns a string, hence you must unwrap:

```
return fmt.stringFromNumber(unwrapped)!
```

There's a difference between these 2:

```
return fmt.stringFromNumber(unwrapped!)
return fmt.stringFromNumber(unwrapped)!
```